# Late medieval music - Queen of the Poles - Interpretation

Tags: classical-music, history

I found [some basic info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llibre_Vermell_de_Montserrat) about a piece titled "Polorum Regina," which is part of a larger collection known as Llibre Vermell de Montserrat. The pieces have a devotional feel / spirit as is reflected by the titles and lyrics. Most of which are easy to understand; titles like: "O Splendid Virgin" or "Praise Mary" have rather obvious biblical contexts.

"Queen of the Poles," (English translation of Polorum Regina) on the other hand, isn't a devotional term I've heard before. In my research, I saw that there is also a folk element to the pieces; perhaps Queen of the Poles does not have a biblical reference but rather something folk-related. Either way, I could only come up with two interpretations -- neither of which seem that convincing.

- A reference to the Queen of Poland, but I don't think that fits as
  there wasn't during that time. Plus the region these songs come from
  is the Mediterranean.
- Another honorific applied to the Virgin Mary: "Queen of the Poles" as
  in ruler of all between North Pole and South Pole, effectively a
  fancy way to say 'of all creation.' However, search engine queries
  using this term didn't return very many matches. So I'm skeptical.

### Question

What is the appropriate way to interpret "Queen of the Poles" as it relates to that musical score / sources of Late Medieval musical inspiration?

Comment: Virgin Mary is in fact queen of Poland. Polorum regina suits here perfectly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Polorum' is the genitive plural of 'polus'. According to several dictionaries 'polus' can mean either a pole or heaven, sky, celestial vault. The second meaning is is probably closer to the intentions of the writer.

The beginning of the text is:

> Polorum regina omnium nostra
> Stella matutina dele scelera

Translated [here](https://dick.wursten.be/Vermell_originaltexts_translations.htm) as :

> Our queen encompassing all of heaven,
> morning star, take away our sins.